# Significance of > commands in Stata

Tags: stata

I am reading a textbook on finance and it has applications that use Stata. There are commands that begin with a . which is the default starter in the Stata command window and these commands I can run just fine. However there are other commands that begin with a > and when I enter these commands with the default . Stata will not recognize them. I havent used this package for a long time, so I dont know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` sign at the start of a physical line in discussions of Stata is just a continuation sign produced in Stata output showing that the text on that physical line follows on from the previous line. In  typing such commands you should always omit the `>` markers.

If you see this

```
. sysuse auto, 
> clear
```

it just is equivalent to

```
. sysuse auto, clear
```

Count the opening `.` not the `>`. What is above is one command (**not** two).

Real examples will be (much) longer, but that is the principle.

Comment: Is there a need for comma?

Comment: Yes; it indicates that options follow. Do please try to read the help and introductory documentation! `help sysuse` would tell you that.